# Why is Cheerio not able to extract tags from this site?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to extract a metatag called og:title from this site:
https://www.nordstrom.com/s/zella-high-waist-studio-pocket-7-8-leggings/5460106?origin=coordinating-5460106-0-1-FTR-recbot-recently_viewed_snowplow_mvp&recs_placement=FTR&recs_strategy=recently_viewed_snowplow_mvp&recs_source=recbot&recs_page_type=category&recs_seed=0&color=BLACK

As you can see in the page source, it is there:

```
<meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:title" content="Zella High Waist Studio Pocket 7/8 Leggings | Nordstrom"/>
```

But when I run the below, I get the following undefined in console:

```
console.log("Title:", $("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content"));
```

```
6:29:39 PM web.1 |  Title: undefined
```

Is it the data-react-helmet or some other option that is causing this to fail?

EDIT: I tried just doing a regular title as well, didn't work.

```
console.log($("title"));
```

```
6:53:25 PM web.1 |  initialize {
6:53:25 PM web.1 |    '0':
6:53:25 PM web.1 |     { type: 'tag',
6:53:25 PM web.1 |       name: 'title',
6:53:25 PM web.1 |       namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
6:53:25 PM web.1 |       attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
...
```

The text should be in the attribs object, but that's empty. I'm not sure what Nordstrom's doing. This works on every other site I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Nordstrom is built with React client side rendering. If you do a `GET` request to that URL (using a tool like Postman or curl) you can see that there are no metatags. The meta tags are dynamically inserted by javascript, and cheerio does not execute javascript, so it does not execute.

Unfortunately there is no simple fix. It may be possible to spoof the user agent to get a pre-rendered version, but I tried and was unsuccessful. You can use a tool like puppeteer https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer which will run the javascript to get you a rendered version of the site, but that is more complex than cheerio.